# ProgressBar same timing as a function

Tags: python-3.x, progress-bar

I want the progress bar to be the same timing with a function, starts when it starts and stop when it is finished

I tried using while loops but it didn't work out.

```
def clean(path):
    for path in paths:
        try:
            rmtree(path)
        except OSError:
            pass
while clean is True:
    for i in range(1):
        sys.stdout.write("%s" % (" " * toolbar_width))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stdout.write("\b" * (toolbar_width + 1))  

        for i in range(toolbar_width):
            sleep(0.1)  # do real work here
            # update the bar
            sys.stdout.write("█████")
            sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stdout.write("\nDone Cleaning\n")
```

I expect the progress bar to print it out according to the `clean()` function
when it is running it will run and when it is done it stops.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This snippet isn't syntactically correct and is not a [mcve], so there's no way to reproduce your problem. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ":" after your "True" statement. Your code is otherwise correct. Just make sure you check over your work! It should look like:

```
def clean(path):
    for path in paths:
        try:
            rmtree(path)
        except OSError:
            pass
    while clean is True:
        for i in range(1):
            sys.stdout.write("%s" % (" " * toolbar_width))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stdout.write("\b" * (toolbar_width + 1))  

            for i in range(toolbar_width):
                sleep(0.1)  # do real work here
                # update the bar
                sys.stdout.write("█████")
                sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stdout.write("\nDone Cleaning\n")
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I meant by the progressbar had to be in time with the clean function, like the progress finishes when the clean function finishes.